# Data Formatting in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to format a text in Java. If the input text is:

> 'Hi all
>
> How are you?
>
> Welcome'

I want the output as:

> 'Hi all
>   How are you?
>   Welcome'

But I am getting output as

> 'Hi allHow are you?Welcome'

My code is

```
while scanner.HasNext(){
s+=scanner.NextLine().replaceAll("\n+" "\n");
System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Can you please upload the full source code or insert a code snippet?

Comment: I am storing it in a text file. Reading from it and appending to a string variable

Comment: Have you tried to add a space to the replace query ? You remove the next line character but you need to add a space too

Comment: `s = str.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\r\\n)+", " ")` ?

Comment: @AxelH yes, I added

Comment: Most likely you are using `readLine()` or `nextLine()` and forgetting to add a separator like space.

Comment: yes Peter. I am using nextLine(). How to add a separator?

Comment: Where is your "Input Text" coming from ? is it also a String object ? or from the console  or somewhere else ?

Comment: addnig to Aarons comment, i would also filter out all whitespaces before/after the new-lines so that there is only 1 resulting space: `s = str.replaceAll("\\s*(\\r|\\n|\\r\\n)+\\s*", " ")`

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show your code of where your input comes from?

Comment: After the edit: Please show us your __real__ code, not some fictional stuff which obviously doesn't work. Adding wrong code to the question isn't helpful, so please take more care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the question is formatted correctly and you are trying to

- read a file (according to the comments)
- remove empty lines

Then, as you read the file into a string, check if not `line.isEmpty()` before you append the line

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
    if (line.isEmpty()) continue;
    sb.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
}
System.out.print(sb.toString());
```

Comment: It is throwing me NoSuchElement exception

Comment: Shouldn't as long as your input file has newline characters in it

Answer (score 0):

You want it to be replace with a space, correct?

```
str.replaceAll("\n+","\n"));
```

Comment: actually I need new line character, But only 1 new line character. If it has more, they need to be ignored

Comment: @Ramya at the end of the string? Then just concatenate that after you replace

Comment: Yeah, proper formatting is important as your question first showed as just spaces not new lines. I'll relook at it.

Comment: Your answer has two issues: too many parenthese and it doesn't work for windows files (windows line ending style).

Comment: str.replaceAll("(\r?\n)+", "\n"));

this?

Comment: You should avoid using `"\n"`. Look for the class `java.lang.System`, it has something that is helpful here.

Comment: I'm guessing you meant lineSeparator() but the answer above mine looks a lot nicer.

Comment: If you prefer "nicer" code which fails on certain system, then that's your choice.

Comment: @tom I meant cricket's answer. Not saying mine is great. His seems to work on all systems.